# IDE to run Protractor .ts files

Tags: ide, protractor

I want to know what is the good IDE for running protractor files (.ts) files? I was using webstrom and it worked very well for me. Since my client wants to use visual studio with typescript, i have moved to that but could not able to run .ts files.

I have followed below steps:

1. installed tnode js tools for vs 2013
2. install typescript 1.7 for vs 2013
3. create a new solution ->typescript -> html application with typescript
4. installed jasmine definetely typed,angular-protractor defintely typed,selenium-webdriver.d.ts,node.d.ts
5. added the reference path and import to conf file

When i build and run, no build errors but it goes to localhost and not the url which i have specified in config file.how to resolve this? is it good idea to use visual studio or not?

Comment: kishan one quick qn
in visual studio code, how to run the conf file?
i mean directly will it launch the browser
or run through the command prompt only

Comment: ok thanks..i will give a try

Comment: hi kishan gm, i havent tried it yet..will try and let you know...thanks

Comment: @KishanPatel, will i be able to debug through vs code?

Comment: thanks @KishanPatel

Comment: @KishanPatel, reg the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510050/protractor-how-to-identify-element?noredirect=1#comment74076828_43510050 can you take a look at the recent comment of mine? it is not working...can you advice what is missing?

Comment: @KishanPatel i have setup the vscode and added the scripts and folders. if i click on debug, it asks to me configure in launch.json ; below is the launch.json - https://pastebin.com/u0XuimBP if i click on debug, it says timeout. i am for sure missing something. can you please guide me

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4070

Comment: ok...but is debugging working for you?

Comment: Sure thankyou so much. Thanks for the reply in between your busy schedule.I have a strong feeling that something is missing.Whenever you have time please take a look.