# protractor - how to identify element

Tags: protractor

In the below page,I have to verify whether "test_tracker" is present or not. I am sure how to do that. can any one help? I thought of `gng` by `ng-repeat` but it is  giving zero.

```
element.all(by.repeater("item in 
ct.data.pageContentTypes")).count().then(function (count) {
            console.log("count value: " + count);
```

what else approach i can go by?

[image: verify]

code snippet:

```html
<div ng-class="detailsChecked ? 'col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <!-- ngRepeat: item in ct.data.pageContentTypes -->
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in ct.data.pageContentTypes">
    <a class="thumbnail" documents-dropzone="" data-category-id="1" ng-click="getContentTypeDetailsByID(item)">
      <div ng-class="selectedContentTypeId == '1' ? 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-public' : 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private'" class="thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private">
        <span style="word-break:break-all;" class="ng-binding">CORE</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in ct.data.pageContentTypes -->
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in ct.data.pageContentTypes">
    <a class="thumbnail" documents-dropzone="" data-category-id="72" ng-click="getContentTypeDetailsByID(item)">
      <div ng-class="selectedContentTypeId == '72' ? 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-public' : 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private'" class="thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private">
        <span style="word-break:break-all;" class="ng-binding">march 13 tt</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in ct.data.pageContentTypes -->
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in ct.data.pageContentTypes">
    <a class="thumbnail" documents-dropzone="" data-category-id="80" ng-click="getContentTypeDetailsByID(item)">
      <div ng-class="selectedContentTypeId == '80' ? 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-public' : 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private'" class="thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private">
        <span style="word-break:break-all;" class="ng-binding">NTC NZ MO</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in ct.data.pageContentTypes -->
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in ct.data.pageContentTypes">
    <a class="thumbnail" documents-dropzone="" data-category-id="87" ng-click="getContentTypeDetailsByID(item)">
      <div ng-class="selectedContentTypeId == '87' ? 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-public' : 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private'" class="thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private">
        <span style="word-break:break-all;" class="ng-binding">test_tracker</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in ct.data.pageContentTypes -->
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in ct.data.pageContentTypes">
    <a class="thumbnail" documents-dropzone="" data-category-id="26" ng-click="getContentTypeDetailsByID(item)">
      <div ng-class="selectedContentTypeId == '26' ? 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-public' : 'thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private'" class="thumbnail-cat thumbnail-cat-private">
        <span style="word-break:break-all;" class="ng-binding">Tracker Test 0119</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in ct.data.pageContentTypes -->
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate the grid table value in protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108617/how-to-validate-the-grid-table-value-in-protractor)

Comment: no..this is different. it is not as a grid.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you are asking the same question for the third time, only in a different context, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245836/verify-table-data-in-protractor) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108617/how-to-validate-the-grid-table-value-in-protractor).

Have you ever tried the `filter()` option? Or are you having troubles using the Protractor commands?

Comment: doesn't mater if it's a grid or not, you want to walk through an [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)

Comment: i will give try now...thanks

Comment: but if i go by ng-repeat the value of count is zero; so should i use other element finder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142132/discussion-between-kavitha-and-wswebcreation).

Comment: @wswebcreation hi, i have tried as below; no error but also i didnt got any output. is there i m missing something here?                                                      it('verify notification', function () {
        browser.sleep(10000);
       
        element.all(by.repeater('item in ct.data.pageContentTypes')).filter(function (elem) {
            return elem.element(by.css('a div.thumbnail-cat span')).getText().then(function (text) {
                
                console.log(text);
                });
            });
        })

Comment: What count you are getting with following xpath  `//span[@style='word-break:break-all;']`

element.all(by.xpath('//span[@style='word-break:break-all;']')).count().then(function (count) {
            console.log("count value: " + count);

Answer (score 0):

finally, below code is working to resolve it

```html
element.all(by.repeater('role in roles.pageitems')).count().then(function (count) 
{            
 console.log("Total number of entries are : " + count)
element.all(by.repeater('role in roles.pageitems')).map(function(elm) {

  return elm.getText();   
}).then(function(texts) {
  console.log("Entries are " + texts);
  expect(texts).toContain("" + a + ""); 
});
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Xpath for this,

var track = element(by.xpath(//span[text()='test_tracker']));

track.isPresent().then(function(){

console.log("track is visible");

})

Comment: Try to avoid `element(by.xpath('...'))` because you don't want the html structure in your `ElementFinder`. Try to stick to the defaults like the `ng-repeat` and so on. Secondly the `isPresent()` tells nothing about the fact that it is visible. It only says that the element is present in the DOM, see [this](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent)

Comment: Angular 2 doesnt support protractor locators (ng-repeat) i guess

Comment: you are right, just talked to @kavatiha and it's an Angular 2 app. He can also use `$$('[ng-repeat="item in ct.data.pageContentTypes"]')`

Comment: But I could see that u have downvoted my comment and replied to mine